# From pyspark agg function to int

Tags: pyspark

I am counting rows by a condition on pyspark

```
df.agg(count(when((col("my_value")==0),True))).show()
```

It works as I expected. Then how can I extract the value showed in the table to store to a Python variable?

Comment: Refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53667451/how-do-i-extract-a-value-i-want-an-int-not-row-from-a-dataframe-and-do-simple/53668087#53668087

Comment: I see someone mentioned ``collect`` function but it does not work in my case: the dataframe is too big and spark will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to count the Trues (ceros), you should better do this:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
pythonVariable = df.where(F.col('my_value') == 0).collect[0][0]
```

As you can see, there is no need to change the ceros to True to count them.